Audio output to mic input using Voicemeeter on an EC2 instance
I've got a Windows EC2 instance that I'm accessing via RDP. I think I've got Voicemeeter set up so that the audio output on the EC2 instance is being piped into the microphone input on the EC2 instance (testing this by playing a Youtube video on the EC2 instance and watching virtual input and virtual output levels in Voicemeeter). To do this, I changed the Windows input device to Voicemeeter Out B1 and the output device to Voicemeeter Input.
The part where it breaks is in browser on the EC2 instance---when I try to do a mic test (playing a Youtube video, sending the audio to Voicemeeter) on a website that uses the microphone, for some reason the browser either doesn't think it has permissions (Edge) or says that the mic is muted/isn't picking up anything (Firefox). In both browser's settings, I've allowed microphone access. I've also tried this connecting via TeamViewer, to no success.
My end goal is to remotely access my Windows EC2 instance, play an .mp3 on the instance, and have that audio be registered as mic input on the instance. Any help would be much appreciated!
Update: I've also tried this with Parsec now, and running into the same problem.

Figured it out with Parsec! I haven't tested it out with TeamViewer or RDP since, but what fixed it while using Parsec was just going into Microphone privacy settings in Windows on the EC2 instance and allowing apps to access the microphone. Allowing microphone access through the browser pop-up alone isn't enough! After allowing it in Windows, the mic test website was able to pickup the virtual mic input from Voicemeeter.
